# Error No provider for e

Tags: angular

I don't understand this error. It is occurring only when I'm clicking one link which has a router to `/adminsection`. This was working fine, but now it is not working.

> vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): Error: No provider for e! Error: No provider for e!
>       at E (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at O (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._throwOrNull (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._getByKey (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.get (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at Be (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.get (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at An (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at En (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at E (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at O (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._throwOrNull (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t._getByKey (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.get (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at Be (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.get (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at An (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at En (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at u (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2544)
>       at u (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2525)
>       at polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2578
>       at e.invokeTask (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2342)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.5593a633d149efa93b2d.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.invokeTask (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2342)
>       at r.runTask (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2169)
>       at o (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2007)
>       at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:2407)
>       at h (polyfills.67d068662b88f84493d2.bundle.js:formatted:1416)

Comment: Did you investigate if this an angular [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19267)?

Comment: @jeroen, Actually it was working yesterday, when i again did a ng serve --prod -aot --port 4500, it is working but on clicking particular link which is basically a adminsection, it is throwing this error. In the admin section i'm using reactive forms which was working but now it is not working.

Comment: @PCA did you try my solution? is it useful to yo or not? l

Comment: @Ajmal Sha, Actually i'm not using cookies package in my project, so it should be an issue i feel, you have any idea why this error comes